# Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [

Tags: mysql, r, connection, odbc

I have been trying to connect to my SQL that I am trying to create. I recently downloaded MySQL, the workbench, the connector ODBC, and the ODBC Manager, but I can't find the solution to solve the error for the connection.
Do I need to download anything else? I can't find a solution on internet or youtube for Mac.

```
packages_required = c("quantmod", "RSQLite", "data.table", "lubridate", "pbapply", "DBI")
install.packages(packages_required)

library("quantmod")
library("RSQLite")
library("data.table")
library("lubridate")
library("pbapply")
library("odbc")

PASS <- new.env()
assign("pwd","My Password",envir=PASS)

library("DBI")
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "/usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.28-macos11-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc8w.so", 
                 Server = "localhost", Database = "data", UID = "root", PWD = PASS$pwd, 
                 Port = 3306)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "/usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.28-macos11-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc8w.so", 
+                  Server = "localhost", Database = "data", UID = "root", PWD = PASS$pwd, 
+                  Port = 3306)
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [ 
>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're on Windows, try creating an ODBC connection using the most recent driver. The ODBC data sources tool should already be installed, you just need to open it and create a new one.

Press the windows key (or click the search spyglass) and type in "ODBC." The "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)" tool should come up.

**How to Create an ODBC Connection in Windows**

1. Open the "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)" application
2. Click "Add"
3. Choose"MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver" (or whatever the newest version you
   have is). If you don't have it, you can download it here:
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
4. Enter the following information:
   Data source name (the example code below uses "my_odbc_connection"), TCP/IP Server, Port, User and Password
5. Click "Details" to expand the box.
6. In the "Connection" tab, you may need to check the "Enable Cleartext
   Authentication" box. Could depend on your system configuratoin.
7. Click "Test" to test the connection. If everything went right you
   should get "Connection Successful" message. If you aren't able to get a
   successful connection, make sure that you have access and that your
   connection information doesn't have any typos.
8. After making a successful connection, perform these 2 additional steps (the
   drop-downs won't populate until you connect successfully):
9. Click the "Database" drop down to choose the default database that you'll
   be writing data to. If you will be writing to more than 1 database
   then you may need to create a separate connection for each database
   that you'll be writing to, specifying the default database
   differently for each one.
10. Click the "Character Set" drop down and choose utf8.

You should now able to use the "DBI" and "ODBC" packages to read, write, etc. any data directly from R. Specific settings listed above may or may not apply depending on situation.

See the example code below.

Further reading: https://www.r-bloggers.com/setting-up-an-odbc-connection-with-ms-sql-server-on-windows/

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Load or install packages
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Load or install librarian
if(require(librarian) == FALSE){
    install.packages("librarian")
  if(require(librarian)== FALSE){stop("Unable to install and load librarian")}
}

# Load multiple packages using the librarian package
librarian::shelf(tidyverse, readxl, DBI, lubridate, ODBC, quiet = TRUE)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Read
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Connect to a pre-defined ODBC connection named "my_odbc_connection"
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "my_odbc_connection")

# Create a query 
query <- "
  SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE;
"

# Run the query
df_data <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn,query)

# Close the open connection
try(DBI::dbDisconnect(conn), silent = TRUE)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Write
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Define the connection and database you'll be writing to
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "my_odbc_connection", db ="YOUR_DEFAULT_DB")

# Define variable types for your data frame. As a general rule, it's a good idea to define your data types rather than let the package guess. 
field_types <- c("INTEGER","VARCHAR(20)","DATE","DATETIME","VARCHAR(20)","VARCHAR(50)","VARCHAR(20)")
names(field_types) <- names(df_data)

# Record start time
start_time <- Sys.time()

# Example write statement
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,"YOUR_TABLE_NAME",YOUR_DATA_FRAME,overwrite=TRUE,field.types=field_types, row.names = FALSE)

# Print time difference
print("Writing complete.")
print(Sys.time() - start_time)

# Close the open connection
try(DBI::dbDisconnect(conn), silent = TRUE)
```